# Get facebook feed for particular users C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a server application that should be able to react to the amount of likes for some of the posts in the user's feed.

I need to get post from users wall.

I'm using [Facebook](http://facebooksdk.net/) library version 6.4.2

I use the following code to get the posts:

```
     var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"];
     var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"];
     var client = PostHandler.CreateFacebookClient(apiKey, secret);
     var get = client.Get(string.Format("/{0}/feed", pageId));
```

and/or  (both return the same info)

```
     var token =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"];
     var get = client.Get(string.Format("/{0}/feed?access_token={1}", pageId, token));
```

The problem is that using the same set of permissions the json returned from the request above is different from the json returned from json returned from [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/404760079630151/?method=GET&path=100000481752436/feed)  methog GET 100000481752436/feed

In my opinion the json returned from my request is missing some posts and the one from the Geaph API all contains the posts from my feed.

Could you please advice, what could I have missed ?

Comment: please add the details about the data you need, that is missed in the json returned from your request. otherwise it is hard to guess ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are missing some posts in the feed it is most likely that you'll have to check the permissions set again.

Based on the type of posts you are missing you maybe have to add the `user_status`, `user_activities`, `user_friends`, `user_checkins` or `user_games_activity` permissions. Please make sure that you're using the correct set of the permissions for your particular task.

If you'll specify the type of the posts you are missing you may get much more helpful answers.